# Products stopped showing for a couple of hours with Magento

Tags: magento, caching, indexing, magento-1.4

I've come across a strange issue where over the weekend one of our websites stopped displaying any products when clicking on a product category. One of my collegues tested and was getting the usual error message 'There are no products matching the selection'. I tested it later in the day and it was working fine.

I'm wondering if it was something to do with the cache management, but i don't know how any of this works. I've not worked on the site before so Magento is new to me. There is also a feature within 'index managment' where it looks like it runs every 24/48 hours.

I need to be able to give some information back to a client. Any helps would be appreciated. I hope the information is enough to go on.

```
Magento ver. 1.4.1.1
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

If I manually reindex the data on the 'product pricing' index. This seems to solve the problem. However I need to workout what's causing it from stopping in the first place. Is there a way I can see when the index management was run and if an error was given?

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the Indexes was refreshing. Most likely the "catalog_category_products".

To be sure, just manually re-index it in the Backoffice, and check whether your products appears in front or not.

If not, check the others indexes.

Comment: Do you know how long it would take to run? It could be that they ran on the weekend and that's why we had the problem. However the products were not appearing for a few hours. It could be a problem that has been there for a while, just never picked up on.

Comment: It depends on your server and database (products / categories / attributes / sotres / etc) .. Can be a few seconds to several hours or days ..

Comment: Ok, so the problem is happening at the moment and i've tried doing a manual refresh on the index management. Really not sure what the problem is. Something is running and it's either causing an error or taking a long time to run.

Comment: Update: I've just manually refreshed the 'Product prices' Index management and the products are now showing as they should on the site. Seems strange that it runs fine when i manually run it. Would that mean it's the 'product pricing' index or would it the one that runs before it? Thanks!

Comment: check you server processes (htop + mysql processlist statut + cron logs, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Might be an issue with your cronjob, so that automatic indexing of your products isn't working properly. You can check for this in the DB, look into the table `cron_schedule` and check if the index-process ran succesfully. You can see the time it ran and compare to the time your products were visible again. 
If this is your issue, you might want to make sure your `cron.php` gets called regularly and ensure, that all scheduled cronjobs are executed properly.

Comment: Thanks, i'll see if i can access the database to check the table. Is there somewhere I can view the Cronjobs that have been setup?

Comment: I can recommend you this tool for keeping track of Magento's cron handling: http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-cron-scheduler.html . It shows you all information about Magento tasks which are handled by cronjob as well as a when they got executed and with which status they exited.